# RSelenium: `describeElement` not working

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")  # Works
webElem <- remDr$findElement("partial link text", "download R")  # Works
webElem$getElementText()  # Works
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
webElem$describeElement() # Doesn't work!
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException
```

My ultimate goal is to get the list of all children of the `webElem`, so that I can extract specific attributes of each element.

Any ideas?

I am running Firefox on Mac OS X with R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09).

Comment: This command is currently undefined https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#GET_/session/:sessionId/element/:id . "Note: This command is reserved for future use; its return type is currently undefined."

Comment: @jdharrison That should be an answer